# Largest LMDB Map Size on Ubuntu Running in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lmdb

Prior to creating a new database, I set LMDB's map size to 5 GiB via its native C `mdb_env_set_mapsize()` function, and all return codes from this and other LMDB functions needed to work with the database indicate success.

However, once I begin using the sole, unnamed database in the LMDB environment, I receive a "map full" error after the database grows to 1 GiB.

I checked available memory in the bash window with `free -m` and saw that 6.7 GiB of memory is used and 9.4 GiB is *free*.

My gut tells me this is an OS rather than LMDB issue.  Does anyone know where I could begin diagnosing (and fixing) the root cause?

Using:

- Windows 10 ver. 1803, build 17134.345
- Ubuntu ver. 16.04 within WSL
- LMDB ver. 0.9.17-3
- 16 GiB of physical memory

Answer (score 0):

I almost refrained from posting the embarrassing answer... turns out this is neither an OS nor LMDB issue.  Summary of the original code causing a 1 GiB maximum map size was:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <lmdb.h>

int pageSize;
MDB_env *env;

pageSize = getpagesize();   /* OS-dependent number of bytes in a memory page */
mdb_env_create(&env);
mdb_env_set_mapsize(env, (int)(5*1024*1024*1024 / pageSize) * pageSize);
...
```

The `int` type cast, present for rounding purposes, in the last function was the culprit.  Changing it to `long int` solved the problem.  The joys of C...